# NOT EQUAL in aws cloud search

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

Is there a way to do search like NOT EQUAL in aws cloud search. I have an attribute language. Basically I want to add filter like result not equal to "en". How can I do so in aws cloud search. I want to avoid adding additional attribute in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negate a query using the `NOT` operator. In your case:

`NOT language:'en'`

Have a look at the docs for more examples http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching-compound-queries.html